# Preventing R From Rounding inside the "expression" function

Tags: r

I need to show exactly 98.0 in the plot, but R unfortunately only show 98 +- 2.3 Omega

```
  text(0.03,8,  expression(Rx ==    98.0   +-  2.3* phantom(x)*Omega), cex = 1.5, col = "red")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot( x = 1:10, y = 1:10 )
text(4,8,
     expression( Rx == '98.0'   %+-%  2.3 *phantom(x)* Omega ),
     cex = 1.5, col = "red")
```

[image]